# Resetting a private static int from a junit test class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am trying to write some junit tests for a class called Student. Basically, each student has a studentNum which is being set to an iterator which is a private static int. Every time a new Student is created, studentNum is incremented.

I have several tests for a function that gets the Student with a studentNum of 1 from a passed in arraylist of Students. However, each time I make a new arraylist of students in a new test, studentNum starts where the previous test's studentNum left off. So the first test will make Students with studentNums from 0 through 5, and the second test will make students with studentNums from 6 through 11.

I was wondering if there is a way to reset the private static studentNum integer from my test class, so that I can have it start at 0 for each test? Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Probably you want a `@Before` method that is called before each test.

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: Just create a new `Student` fixture before each test method.

Comment: The right answer is almost certainly "don't use static variables for this purpose and use an external counter instead".

Comment: Create a new  StudentList ( or StudentFactory or whatever you name your state) object, make the counter a non static field and if you put that into a before method you have a always clean test context and no dependencies or missing cleanups.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you find this hard to test is a warning sign that you probably need to rethink your design. Ask yourself this: why should the `Student` class be responsible for generating a unique id?

If you separate the id generation logic (even if it's as simple as incrementing a single counter) into a separate class, suddenly you'll be able to mock that class while you're testing `Student` and have it return any id you want in your tests.

Comment: Or you just instantiate `Student` with an ID picked in the test.

Comment: @chrylis Yes, there are many ways to feed the id into the student object, if it is required. But the important thing is the single responsibility principle: the `Student` class should not be responsible for the id generation (or keeping a list of the instances, or anything similar).

Answer (score 2):

> **each student** has a studentNum which is a private **static** int

This statement makes no sense. If each instance of your Student object is to have its own id, the `id` field should *not* be static, by definition.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. There is actually a private static iterator in the Student class which the studentNum is being set to in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `@Before/@After` annotations. Methods annotated like this get called before/after each test case is run. You can reset your data there.

```
@Before
public void setup(){

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just think about what static decalration means...
For real purposes studentNum must not be static if it holds Student distinctive number. with static all your Student objects will have latest studentNum.

But if it is a requirement (cannot imagine for what ...), just for junit with multiple @Test methods (and only with) [R O M A N I A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3885376/r-o-m-a-n-i-a) is correct. Do this:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Student.studentNum =0;
}
```

It will reset static studentNum before execution of each @Test method call.

Answer (score -2):

You can have a `@Before` or an `@After` (or both) in which you reset the private static field to whatever value you wish (e.g. 0), using Java's Reflection API.

The way to do that would be:

```
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    Field studentNum = Student.class.getDeclaredField("studentNum");
    studentNum.setAccessible(true); //to overcome the visibility issue
    studentNum.setInt(null, 0); //null since it's static
}
```

Comment: While this approach is possible you should not use it. accessing a private member of an object (even for a test) violates the most important principle in OOP: *information hiding*! Also: if you start testing implementation details (instead ob behavior) your tests will bite you if you want to refactor your code.

Comment: I agree with you that having to use reflection in tests is most probably a `code smell`. However, what you suggest is how to better structure the code, in order to keep it well encapsulated and with single responsibility, making it testable in the process, while the OP wanted to keep the code as-is, but overcome the testability problem, which is a pretty valid scenario, especially in cases of old/legacy code where refactoring is not an easy process and most probably not worth it (business-wise).

Comment: *"while the OP wanted to keep the code as-is, but overcome the testability problem"* When is the best time to start better coding? For me is *now*. Giving the OP the reflections solution enables her to sick to the broken coding/testing style. Do *you* want a coworker doing what the OP tries to do? *I* don't!